# Visual Studio suddenly appearing white

Tags: visual-studio

My Visual studio has suddenly started showing white screen when I change the theme to black. Please help me regarding this.

[image]

Comment: Did you try restarting VS after changing the theme?

Comment: Are you sharing the Visual Studio account with someone else?

Comment: @ManuelFabbri Yes I am sharing with one of my friends

Comment: @phuzi I have tried restarting but It was not working

Answer (score 0):

Check if this option is enabled or not: Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Accounts: "*Synchronize settings across devices when signed into Visual Studio*". In your case, it should be **disabled**.